# Update Multiple Row's

Tags: mysql

I would like to change one field of multiple row's at once by user input.

Something like:

I had some books at some branch, and i want to change some of them to other branch.

The user select the books to change (by codebar), and then the db update the field of the branch.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What database? What programming language?

Comment: The database was created by a software "koha" used to manage libraries. The db is mysql!

Comment: Does not look like a programming language but an application. Perhaps better to ask the Koha support center.

Comment: Have you done something at least?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET branch = $new_branch
    WHERE book_id IN (11,22,3344);
```

You would need to construct the list of ids.

Another approach would involve a multi-table `UPDATE` and a tmp table you populate with the book_ids.